# Page not found (404)(No category matches the given query.)

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to activate the navigation bar links using context_processors.py file .Here I used a dropdown menu and some links to load contents in the same html page.Dropdown menu is for selecting the 'category' and links are used for selecting the 'genre'.'category' app is used for adding the categories via admin panel and 'genre' app is used for adding the genres.'review' app is created for display the details.In 'review' app model 'details' is created and 'category' model in the 'category' app and 'genre' model in the 'genre' app is defined in the 'details' model using ForeignKey.I want to display items in the same page(index.html) when clicks a link.Link given in dropdown menu worked properly,but when I click links other than links mentioned in dropdown menu are not working and it display's 404 error like below:

```
Page not found (404)

No category matches the given query.

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/drama/
Raised by:  review.views.index

Using the URLconf defined in movie.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='index']
<slug:category_slug>/ [name='index_by_category']

The current path, drama/, matched the last one.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Can anyone suggest a solution for this.

HTML Page:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<nav class="navbar navbar-main navbar-expand-lg navbar-light border-bottom">
  <div class="container">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main_nav" aria-controls="main_nav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main_nav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link pl-0" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><strong> <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> &nbsp  Category</strong></a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'index' %}">All Category</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              {% for i in links %}
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{i.get_url}}">{{i.category_name}}</a>
              {% endfor %}
          </div>
        </li>
           {% for x in genre_links %}
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{{x.get_url}}">{{x.genre_name}}</a>
        </li>
            {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </div> 
  </div> 
</nav>
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns=[
    path('',views.index,name="index"),
    path('<slug:category_slug>/',views.index,name="index_by_category"),
    path('<slug:genre_slug>/',views.index_by_genre,name="index_by_genre"),
    ]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect,get_object_or_404
from review.models import details
from category.models import category
from genre.models import genre

def index(request,category_slug=None):
    if category_slug!=None:
        categories = get_object_or_404(category,slug=category_slug)
        movies = details.objects.filter(Category=categories)
    else:
        movies = details.objects.all()
    return render(request,"index.html",{'movies':movies})

def index_by_genre(request,genre_slug=None):
    if genre_slug != None:
        genres = get_object_or_404(genre, slug=genre_slug)
        movies = details.objects.filter(Genre=genres)
    else:
        movies = details.objects.all()
    return render(request,"index.html",{'movies':movies})
```

context_processors.py(category)

```
from .models import category
def menu_links(request):
    links = category.objects.all()
    return dict(links=links)
```

context_processors.py(genre)

```
from .models import genre

def menu_links(request):
    genre_links = genre.objects.all()
    return dict(genre_links=genre_links)
```

models.py(genre)

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class genre(models.Model):
    genre_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255,blank=True)
    genre_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='categories',blank=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'genre'
    verbose_name_plural = 'genres'

def get_url(self):
    return reverse('index_by_genre', args=[self.slug])

def __str__(self):
    return self.genre_name
```

models.py(genre)

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255,blank=True)
    cat_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='categories',blank=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'category'
    verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

def get_url(self):
    return reverse('index_by_category',args=[self.slug])

def __str__(self):
    return self.category_name
```

models.py(review app)

```
from django.db import models
from category.models import category
from genre.models import genre

class details(models.Model):
    movie_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    director = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    writer = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cast = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    year_release = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    time = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    Category = models.ForeignKey(category,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Genre = models.ForeignKey(genre,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.movie_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify urls.py file so that we can solve this issue.Remove last two paths from urls.py file.Put `path('<slug:category_slug>/',views.index,name="index_by_category"),`code in urls.py file of category app and `path('<slug:genre_slug>/',views.index_by_genre,name="index_by_genre"),` in urls.py file of genre app.Also remove  'index_by_genre' function from views.py and put it in views.py file of genre app.Similarly for 'category'.Do not forgot to give connection between app urls and project urls.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I swapped the paths and it got. I mean
Not:

```
path('<slug:category_slug>/',views.index,name="index_by_category"),
path('<slug:genre_slug>/',views.index_by_genre,name="index_by_genre"),
```

Do:

```
path('<slug:genre_slug>/',views.index_by_genre,name="index_by_genre"),
path('<slug:category_slug>/',views.index,name="index_by_category"),
```